# Call methods on an object that will be created by other users

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, reflection

How can I make sure that my classes will be able to call a method defined by me, on objects that will be defined by other users.

I have structured my code following proper design patterns. And on top of the hierarchy   there is an abstract class that is extended by several classes, OTHER USERS will be able to  extend the top class.

In a factory class some methods of the top class are called on the instances of the classes created by me and by the OTHER USERS. But I neither know how those classes are called by the users, how can I call methods on them in the factory class?

- `CarGenerator`  (on top)
- `BlueBiggerCar` [extends CarGenerator]
- `SmallGreenCar` [extends CarGenerator]
- `RedCar`        [extends CarGenerator]
  ...

I let the possibility to the user to add new classes that extend `CarGenerator`, and on a Factory class as `ScreenFactory` the car are disposed on the screen as an example.

In the factory `ScreenFactory` there will be something like:

```
new SmallGreenCar().appearOnScreen(); //A small green car appears on the screen.
```

but the users will add new cars as objects when my code will be released, in that case, how would those cars be able to appear on the screen if I cannot create an instance of them IN THE FACTORY? I'm wrong with the structure of the code probably but I can't understand how to fix.

Comment: Please clarify your question with some code. If the method is abstract in the super class you can just invoke it in your classes and rely on the fact that there must be a concrete implementation for someone to have passed you that instance.

Comment: This sounds like your users should implement an interface that you provide. This way, you know the methods because you defined their type. However, you should rework this question, maybe provide an example. Currently, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: `public abstract void appearOnScreen()`. Done.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch look at some code upper, maybe will be clearer.

Comment: You search for a way to dynamically extend your factory class - that is possible by registering a `Class<T extends BaseClass>` for a given identifier and creating the classes through `Class.newInstance()` but I have not come across a (serious) case where this was needed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider ok for sure that will define a personal way to appear on screen, but how will be shown that new car? On what instance will be the method `.appearOnScreen()` called in the factory?

Comment: @Smutje "dynamically extend factory class" that's what i need, is that reflection?

Comment: @Matt not really - your factory could hold a `Map<String, Class<?>>` and be populated with certain identifiers for which objects of the registered classes can be created at runtime. Similar to `factory.register("smallGreen", SmallGreenCar.class); factory.create("smallGreen");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both, of these design patterns should fulfill the task:

- [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) or the
- [Extensibility pattern aka. Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility_pattern)